# pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

i've got a Problem with an Array of pointers.

```
struct sFace {
sPoint* points[2];        
sCell*  neighCells[2];
sFace*  neighFaces[4];

double* neighPe[4];
double* neighF[4];}

struct sCell {
   sFace*   faces[4];  
   sPoint*  points[4];
   sCell*   neighCells[4];
}

and
curFace = &data->faces[faceId];
curCell = &data->cells[cellId];
```

why i must not use the &-operator in:

```
curFace->neighFaces[1]&= curFace->neighCells[1]->faces[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&=` is a bitwise assignment operator according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators).

Read [C++ Fundamentals](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/cpp-fundamentals) if you are new to programming in C++.

Comment: Oh thank you my friend. And the same question in:  
`curFace->neighPe[XP] = &curFace->neighFaces[XP]->Pe[0];`

Comment: Here the & operator is used as reference operator.

Answer (score 1):

Because the bitwise `&` operator is not defined for pointers:

```
curFace->neighFaces[1]
```

`neighFaces` is a:

```
sCell*   neighCells[4];
```

So, `curFace->neighFaces[1]` is a `sCell *`, and the bitwise `&` operator is not defined for pointers.